# Apostrophe key in one keystroke

Tags: keyboard

Currently, I can insert the apostrophe character `'` only by pressing an extra space after typing the apostrophe key.

My current keyboardsetting is `English (United States) - United States-International`. I've also tried `English (United States) - US`

I'm looking for the configuration setting which inserts the apostrophe character in one keystroke, without having to use the space key.

Supplement.
I'm using both Windows 7 and 10. I'm not using a text-editor, but a web browser application.

Comment: do you really mean apostrophe or the back quote? https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/b/backquot.htm

Comment: @chloesoe I really mean apostrophe.

Comment: This is a property of the International keyboard, are you sure you really need it?

Comment: I'm doing a [typing course](typing.com) which require's the `'` keystroke individually, without the space.

Answer (score 1):

This is a property of the International keyboard. Typing for example the letter
`e` after the apostrophe will create an accented character like `é`.

If you wish to disable this property, there are two options:

- Use the non-international version of the keyboard.
- Use a keyboard-macro with a product such as
  [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Using AutoHotKey, you may map <kbd>apostrophe</kbd> to
<kbd>apostrophe</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> with a script like this:

```
#UseHook, On
':: send '{Space}
```

The `#UseHook` directive is needed to avoid an infinite loop on the
repeated interception of the apostrophe.
Hotkeys that use the keyboard hook cannot be triggered by means of the
Send command.